# RTF using Hebrew in Z-Tree on Windows

Tags: windows, encoding, utf-8, rtf

I'm currently using z-tree (the Zurich Toolbox for Readymade Economic Experiments) for programming an experiment. I using a lot of formatting in Hebrew letters, which display correctly using my MAC. When I try running the experiment file on Windows, the Rich Text Formatting seems to not be encoded: sentences with numbers are all messed up.

I changed to locale language to Hebrew but I don't know what else should I do. 
Any suggestions? 
Thanks!